# I'm trying to create a container from an image of a small project, but I get an error: docker: Error response from daemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "server.js"]
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const app = express();
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const productRouter = require('./routes/productsRoutes');
const swaggerFile = require('./swagger/swagger_output.json');

const PORT = 8000;

app.use('/doc', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerFile));
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server rodando em: http://localhost:${PORT}`)
});

app.use('/api', userRouter);
app.use('/api/products', productRouter);
```

**The error**:
*docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "nodemon": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.*

**The command**
docker run -d -p 8000:8080 projeto-pratico-api/node

*projeto-pratico-api/node = name of the image

Comment: how did you install`nodemon`?

Answer (score 1):

Your main container process is `nodemon`, but it's not installed in your image.  Since a Docker image contains an immutable copy of the application code, it will never change while the container is running, and you don't need a monitoring tool like `nodemon`; just set the main container process to run `node`.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server.js"]
#            ^^^^ not nodemon
```

Comment: I understood your point, but didn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing nodemon from your Dockerfile?

Add:

```
RUN npm install -g nodemon
```

Full updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "server.js"]
```

**Second approach, use node instead of nodemon:**

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: i've tried, but didn't work :(

Comment: @VictorAlmeida Check the second approach I posted, and also double check your port, because on your code you are using port 8000 and in docker is 8080